# how to use subexpressions

Tags: prolog

Hello stackoverflow community,
i have a prolog code that creates subexpressions for a truth table and then gives them values true/false
well its working fine for alot of expressions but using this statement this happens

```
1 ?- phrase(subexprs(bicond(and(impl(A,B),impl(B,A)),bicond(A,B))),Subexprs), bindList([A,B]), maplist(expr_value, Subexprs, Values).
A = B, B = true,
Subexprs = [true impl true, true impl true,  (true impl true)and(true impl true), true bicond true,  **(true impl true)and(true impl true)bicond(true bicond true)**],
Values = [true, true, true, true, false] .
```

the last value is not what should be printed
the whole expression should be printed instead which is
bicond((true impl true)and(true impl true),bicond true)

here is my code

```
and(A,B) :- A, B.
or(A,_) :- A.
or(_,B) :- B.
equ(A,B) :- or(and(A,B), and(not(A),not(B))).
xor(A,B) :- not(equ(A,B)).
nor(A,B) :- not(or(A,B)).
nand(A,B) :- not(and(A,B)).
impl(A,B) :- or(not(A),B).
bicond(true,true):-true.
bicond(true,false):-false.
bicond(false,true):-false.
bicond(false,false):-true.


:- op(900, fy,not).
:- op(910, yfx, and).
:- op(910, yfx, nand).
:- op(920, yfx, or).
:- op(920, yfx, nor).
:- op(930, yfx, impl).
:- op(930, yfx, equ).
:- op(930, yfx, xor).
:- op(910, yfx, bicond).


subexprs(V) -->
    { var(V), ! },
    [].
subexprs(and(L, R)) -->
    subexprs(L),
    subexprs(R),
    [and(L, R)].
subexprs(or(L, R)) -->
    subexprs(L),
    subexprs(R),
    [or(L, R)].
subexprs(impl(L, R)) -->
    subexprs(L),
    subexprs(R),
    [impl(L, R)].
subexprs(nand(L, R)) -->
    subexprs(L),
    subexprs(R),
    [nand(L, R)].
subexprs(nor(L, R)) -->
    subexprs(L),
    subexprs(R),
    [nor(L, R)].
subexprs(xor(L, R)) -->
    subexprs(L),
    subexprs(R),
    [xor(L, R)].
subexprs(bicond(L, R)) -->
    subexprs(L),
    subexprs(R),
    [bicond(L, R)].


expr_value(Expr, true) :-
    call(Expr),
    !.
expr_value(_Expr, false).

bind(true).
bind(false).
bindList([]).
bindList([V|Vs]) :- bind(V),bindList(Vs).
```

i think the wrong part is the op
but i dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

With your current definition of `bicond/2`, the call `bicond((true impl true)and(true impl true), bicond(true, true))` will fail: `bicond/2` expects each of its arguments to unify with the term `true` or `false`. But you are calling it with complex terms.

Instead, you have to rewrite the definition to "evaluate" its operand terms, exactly as you do in the definition of `equ/2`.

Comment: Can you tell me the coorrect definition for bico ditional?